# Assign ID to each thread using ThreadLocal

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

In the below program i want to assign distinct id to each thread, but in the output each thread is having inconsistent id's as shown in output. However if I uncomment the system.out statement each thread is assigned unique ID's, not sure about the reason.

```
class ThreadLocalDemo {
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, 
ExecutionException {
    CustomerThread custThread1 = new CustomerThread("Sampath");
    CustomerThread custThread2 = new CustomerThread("Harish");
    CustomerThread custThread3 = new CustomerThread("Harsha");
    CustomerThread custThread4 = new CustomerThread("Gowtham");
    custThread1.start();
    custThread2.start();
    custThread3.start();
    custThread4.start();
    }
}

class CustomerThread extends Thread {
static Integer custId = 0;
private  static ThreadLocal<Integer> tl = new ThreadLocal<Integer>() {
    @Override
    protected Integer initialValue() {
        //System.out.println("will work");
        return ++custId;
    }
};

CustomerThread(String name) {
    super(name);
}

public void run() {
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " executing with id: " + tl.get());
}
}
```

Output is:

```
Sampath executing with id: 1
Harish executing with id: 
Harsha executing with id: 2
Gowtham executing with id: 1
```

Expected output is threads with unique id's:

```
Sampath executing with id: 1
Harish executing with id: 2
Harsha executing with id: 3
Gowtham executing with id: 4
```

Comment: Define "inconsistent id's".

Comment: What output? Oh, that non-code down at the end of the code? Please format the code correctly (indent it correctly), and separate the output from the code, so the question is readable.

Comment: @Andreas: added the output.

Comment: Can you show the output you are receiving and the output that you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not thread-safe, because the `++` operator is not thread-safe.

You should use an [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html), and there is no reason to use [`ThreadLocal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html).

Change your class to this, to assign the ID at time of creation, i.e. in order of creation, not deferred until first use:

```
class CustomerThread extends Thread {
    private static final AtomicInteger prevCustId = new AtomicInteger();
    private final int custId;

    CustomerThread(String name) {
        super(name);
        this.custId = prevCustId.incrementAndGet();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(getName() + " executing with id: " + this.custId);
    }
}
```

*Sample Output*

```
Sampath executing with id: 1
Harsha executing with id: 3
Gowtham executing with id: 4
Harish executing with id: 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You couldn't increment `Integer` safely in different threads, you should use `AtomicInteger` with `getAndIncrement()` method for your case.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your code:

1. Non thread safe incrementing of your static custId value
2. Needless use of a ThreadLocal variable when you are already creating a new instance of this class each time (i.e. a single instance of your class is not being shared across threads, instead each thread already has its own instance of the class).

The fix for issue 1 is to either use an AtomicInteger, or to perform the increment operation within a synchronized block.

The fix for issue 2 is to simply remove the static ThreadLocal variable and simply use a regular non-static variable.

A fixed version of your code:

```
public class ThreadLocalDemo
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        CustomerThread custThread1 = new CustomerThread("Sampath");
        CustomerThread custThread2 = new CustomerThread("Harish");
        CustomerThread custThread3 = new CustomerThread("Harsha");
        CustomerThread custThread4 = new CustomerThread("Gowtham");
        custThread1.start();
        custThread2.start();
        custThread3.start();
        custThread4.start();
    }
}

class CustomerThread extends Thread {
    static AtomicInteger custId = new AtomicInteger(0);
    private int tl;

    CustomerThread(String name) {
        super(name);
        tl = custId.incrementAndGet();
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " executing with id: " + tl);
    }

}
```

Comment: @Freeman I agree that we don't need ThreadLocal to assign ID to each Thread, but curious to see , how ThreadLocal can be used to assign new ID  to each Thread.

Answer (score 1):

What you see here is that `ThreadLocal.initialValue()` and integer incrementation are not thread-safe by default, so their combination will not become thread-safe either.

The 'official' [`ThreadLocal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) example uses AtomicInteger (and that is what others are suggesting too), which makes integer incrementation thread-safe. But you can freely make your `initialValue()` method thread-safe too, by making it `synchronized`:

```
// ... your original code ...
    synchronized protected Integer initialValue() {
// ... your original code ...
```

Then your code will work fine with the simple `Integer`.